# Why am i getting the 'Converting circular structure to JSON' error in nodeJS while running myqsl query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, object

I am doing a mysql query stuff to select the all data in a table  (name LOGIN) and

> https://localhost:2000/select 
>   and the params to be passed in the req.body is the **table_name** value is **login** and
>   when i hit the api using **postman**, it returns an empty set with consolelog says,

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.selecting (/home/andiswamy/Documents/fuDDie/shayam/dbConnection.js:67:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My code is :

```
router.get('/select', async (req, res) =>
{   
    let table_name =  req.headers.table_name;
    try {
        let inserting = await db.selecting(table_name);
        console.log(inserting);

        res.send(stringify(inserting));
        res.end();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

async function selecting(table_name) {
    try {
        let result = await testDB.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table_name}`);
        console.log(typeof result);
        result = JSON.stringify(result);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: what library are you using for making database calls

Answer (score 0):

```
let room = {
  number: 23
};

let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
  participants: ["john", "ann"]
};

meetup.place = room;       // meetup references room
room.occupiedBy = meetup; // room references meetup

JSON.stringify(meetup); // Error: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Refer to the above example this error occours when you refer both the objects to each other and try to stringify them.

Comment: Yeah  @siddhartha varma , thanks,, I got cleared now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a atricle about Circular reference.

[Understanding The Error ‘Converting circular structure to JSON’](https://youshaohua.com/post/understanding-the-error-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

You could use the module [check-circular-reference](https://github.com/ShawnYou1/check-circular-reference) to check whether exist circular reference and print its attribute chain.

and then delete the circular attribute.